# Get most frequent value from a windowing function

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a SQL table that looks like:

```
user_id role    date
1       1       2019-11-26 21:20:54.397+00
1       2       2019-11-27 22:46:28.923+00
2       1       2019-12-06 22:17:53.925+00
2       3       2019-12-13 00:12:28.006+00
3       1       2019-11-25 21:57:17.701+00
3       1       2019-12-06 20:48:28.314+00
3       1       2019-12-15 23:59:06.81+00
4       3       2019-12-04 15:26:10.639+00
4       3       2019-11-22 19:20:01.025+00
4       3       2019-11-25 12:38:53.169+00
```

I would like to get the most frequent role according to past dates and use. The result should looks like:

```
user_id role    date                        most_frequent_role
1       1       2019-11-26 21:20:54.397+00  NULL
1       2       2019-11-27 22:46:28.923+00  1
2       1       2019-12-06 22:17:53.925+00  NULL
2       3       2019-12-13 00:12:28.006+00  1
3       1       2019-11-25 21:57:17.701+00  NULL
3       1       2019-12-06 20:48:28.314+00  1
3       1       2019-12-15 23:59:06.81+00   1
4       3       2019-12-04 15:26:10.639+00  NULL
4       3       2019-11-22 19:20:01.025+00  3
4       3       2019-11-25 12:38:53.169+00  3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your logic, how do you get your expected result? What if there's not a single *most frequent role*?

Comment: At this moment, i don't get my expected result because i don't arrive to get it. You're right, i don't explain this case. If there's not a single most frequent role, roles should be separate by a comma

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work for you.

```
select test.user_id,test.role,test.role_date, 
case when test.role_date in 
(select min(role_date) from test group by user_id) then NULL 
else t.role end as MOST_FREQUENT_ROLE 
from 
(select user_id,min(role) as role from test group by user_id
)t 
join test on t.user_id=test.user_id
order by user_id,role_date
```

Output

```
USER_ID ROLE    ROLE_DATE   MOST_FREQUENT_ROLE
1         1     26-NOV-19    - 
1         2     27-NOV-19    1
2         1     06-DEC-19    - 
2         3     13-DEC-19    1
3         1     25-NOV-19    - 
3         1     06-DEC-19    1
3         1     15-DEC-19    1
4         3     22-NOV-19    - 
4         3     25-NOV-19    3
4         3     04-DEC-19    3
```

Comment: . . Your code is hard to follow but I think it returns the FIRST value rather than the MOST FREQUENT.  Here is a db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e99cb7d517ee3df5dcbfe56ed089f8c7.  For the first user, the most frequent role changes from 1 to 2.

Comment: I dont think so, but i will test the code for the mentioned case and will update the answer accordingly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to go with window function, Try below -

```
SELECT user_id
      ,role
      ,date
      ,CASE WHEN date = MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date)
                 THEN NULL
            ELSE MIN(role) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) END MOST_FREQUENT_ROLE 
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you are trying to calculate is the *mode* (this is a statistical term).

Postgres has a built-in [`mode()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) function.  Alas, it does not work as you need as a window function, so it provides little help.

I would recommend using a lateral join:

```
select t.*, m.role
from t left join lateral 
     (select t2.role
      from t t2
      where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
            t2.date < t.date
      group by t2.role
      order by count(*) desc,
               max(date) desc  -- in the event of ties, use the most recent
      limit 1
     ) m
     on 1=1
order by user_id, date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c43b5e1f384fcc3fbf6604938638c41c) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that I added some rows to give an example of where the running mode changes.

This will not be particularly efficient but an index on `(user_id, date, role)` should help.

If you have just a handful of roles there are probably more efficient solutions.  If that is the case and performance is an issue, ask a *new* question.